# Why can't I compare with an instance property inside a Predicate?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have a master-detail application where the detail view initializes with a `Collection` object and displays all `Item` objects associated with such Collection.

Item model

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var image: Data?
    var collection: Collection?
    
    init(timestamp: Date = Date(), image: Data? = nil, collection: Collection? = nil) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.image = image
        self.collection = collection
    }
}
```

Collection model

```
@Model
final class Collection {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(inverse: \Item.collection) var items: [Item]
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(name: String = "", items: [Item] = [], timestamp: Date = Date()) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

Master view:

```
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var collections: [Collection]
     
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(collections) { collection in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ItemsView(collection: collection)
                    } label: {
                        Text(collection.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select a collection")
        }
    }
```

Said detail view:

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

let collection: Collection

@Query private var items: [Item]

init(collection: Collection) {
    self.collection = collection
    let id = collection.id
    // Q: Why can't I do this right in @Query(...)?
    _items = Query(filter: #Predicate<Item> { item in
        // Q: Why doesn't item.collection?.id == self.collection.id work
        item.collection?.persistentModelID == id
    })
}
```

I have four somewhat inter-related questions (relatively new to Swift development)

1. Why can't I just do `@Query(filter: #Predicate<Item> { item in item.collection == collection }) private var items: [Item]`? That would seem to be the most elegant, but Xcode complains on compile that "Instance member 'collection' cannot be used on type 'ItemsView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?" Is it because when @Query is defined, instantiation hasn't happened yet? So only constants are allowed in this predicate then?
2. How come I have to capture `let id = collection.id` before comparison, instead of just writing `item.collection?.persistentModelID == self.collection.id`? When I do that, it complains that "Key path value type 'PersistentIdentifier' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Optional'".
3. How come `item.collection?.persistentModelID ==` works but not `item.collection?.id`? Shouldn't they be the same thing?
4. Furthermore, why can't I just compare `item.collection == self.collection`? I tried all kinds of unwrapping, for example

```
    if let itemCollection = item.collection {
       return itemCollection == collection
    } else {
       return false
    }
```

This would throw a compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.NilCoalesce<PredicateExpressions.OptionalFlatMap<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable, Collection?>, Collection, PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.Variable, PredicateExpressions.Value>, Bool>, PredicateExpressions.Value>' to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression'

Thank you in advance! I don't think I understand optionals well in the context of SwiftData.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What are `Item` and `Collection`? Show their declarations.

Comment: For #3, `item.collection?.id == id` works for me too. What is the error you got for that? The rest of these issues are all just "by design". You have to keep in mind that the code you write in `#Predicate { ... }` are not actual Swift code - the `#Predicate` macro transforms these into a something that the database can understand (think SQL). This translation process obviously is going to have its limits. There are some things that it just can't handle. A better diagnostic would probably help here.

Comment: Thank you. When I use `item.collection?.id == id`, I get the following error at runtime when I try to load an ItemsView (not at compile time)

Comment: `SwiftData/DataUtilities.swift:65: Fatal error: Couldn't find \Collection.id on Collection with fields [SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "name", keypath: \Collection.name, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil), SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "items", keypath: \Collection.items, defaultValue: nil, metadata: Optional(Relationship - name: , options: [], valueType: Any, destination: , inverseName:  nil), inverseKeypath: Optional(\Item.collection))))), SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "timestamp", keypath: \Collection.timestamp, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil)]`

Comment: Ah it's a runtime error. I didn't actually run the code, so I thought it worked. Well as I said, not everything can be translated, and this case is also one of those things.

Comment: You could try to unwrap collection, `if let collection = item.collection { return collection.id == id } else { return false }` or since it complains about `id` you could use `persistentModelID` instead because sometimes I have seen that `id` doesn’t work for unknown reasons